# How do I fail a Node unit test on the catch of a Promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, assert

I'm doing some unit tests using Node.js and I want to fail a test like this:

```
doSomething()
    .then(...)
    .catch(ex => {
        // I want to make sure the test fails here
    });
```

I'm using Assert, so I found [Assert.Fails](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_fail_actual_expected_message_operator). The problem is that `fails` expects `actual` and `expected`, which I don't have. The Node documentation doesn't say anything about them being required, but the [Chai documentation](http://chaijs.com/api/assert/#method_fail), which is Node compliant, say they are.

How should I fail a test on the `catch` of a promise?

Comment: For a more semantic failure, you probably want to look into wrapping the `catch` callback with a spy, then making it throw if the spy is called.

Comment: @DanPrince, thanks, can you ellaborate?

Comment: @DanPrince. I think I get. You mean I create a `fail` function that throws an exception, than I pass `fail` to catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will use `mocha`, then elegant way would be as following:

```
describe('Test', () => {
  it('first', (done) => {
    doSomething()
    .then(...)
    .catch(done) 
    })
})
```

If your Promise fail, `done` method will be invoked with the thrown exception as a parameter, so code above is equivalent to

```
catch(ex => done(ex))
```

In `mocha` invoking done() with the parameter fails the test.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dedicated spies library, like [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#spies), or you can implement a simple spy yourself.

```
function Spy(f) {
  const self = function() {
    self.called = true;
  };
  self.called = false;
  return self;
}
```

The spy is just a wrapper function which records data about how the function has been called.

```
const catchHandler = ex => ...;
const catchSpy = Spy(catchHandler);

doSomething()
  .then(...)
  .catch(catchSpy)
  .finally(() => {
    assert.ok(catchSpy.called === false);
  });
```

The basic principle is to spy on the catch callback, then use the [finally clause](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise.prototype.finally) of your promise to make sure that the spy hasn't been called.

Comment: Thanks.. You are not using `f`anywhere inside `Spy(f)`, is that intentional?

Comment: I upvoted your answer but accepted the other one. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @andrerpena I left `f` there to show that you could use it inside the spy if you wanted, but in this case, all you needed to know was whether it was called.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered Assert.Ok(false, message)? It's more terse.

Assert.fail is looking to do a comparison and display additional info.

Comment: This would work but isn't this ugly? It's like a if(false) :(

Comment: Yes, ugly, or you can extend the Assert object yourself and write a better method. Assert.Now(message)